# Is it possible to search and remove files that aren't part of a package?

Tags: package-management

So, I've wrecklessly installed tarballs into / and /usr thinking this is what I'm supposed to do! Apparently its not and updating now kind of is difficult. I'm wondering, save for a full blown reinstall if there is a way to clean out hand installed libraries.

I think i might have a way to do it, I found another question asking how to find out what package a file belongs to. I imagine if it has no package I can nuke it?

Comment: It maybe difficult to track them all down and a clean install maybe the best option. Backup all your data first. Their is something i used in the past to Track down and clean unwanted stuff by using Ubuntu Tweak, Janitor Option --- http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

Comment: This is actually in a virtual machine so its easy enough to create a snapshot and try super terrible things. I have ubuntu-tweak but wasn't sure how to use it to track down untracked files.